# Resize button size dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9fL8dde/1/) code . Right now my button size is defined but i want to dynamically resize button according to the text. What should i do to resize button dynamically? I want to do it through javascript

```
 <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="mainContainer">
            <p class="copyrights" id="copyrights"></p>
            <div>
                <img id="Image_Car" src="http://i.share.pho.to/25a090ef_c.png" />
            </div>
                  <div id="headlineText">
            <p id="headline1Txt" >Sample bag1</p>
            <p id="headline2Txt" >Sale Price $25</p>
            <p id="headline3Txt" >Sale $14<p>
        </div>
            <div id="disclaimer" >
               Details*
            </div>
              <div id="Image_logo">
                <img id="Imglogo" src="http://i.share.pho.to/e114a8e1_c.png" />
            </div>

           <div >
           <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  id="ctaBtn"><div id="fadeIn" >  Learn More Now </div></button>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using check system which check windows size and then set the button width height according to your mind . So for check windows size you can take this code and after that add/sub/div this value by your button size ..

```
 function widthheight()

    {
    var w=window.outerWidth;
    var h=window.outerHeight;
    var button="Window size: width=" + w + ", height=" + h;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=txt;
    }
```

may be my idea help you 
Thanks

Comment: you can add this code by using **onresize** event of javascript

Answer (score 0):

Just don't set the `width` attribute on the button in your CSS. It will be sized to fit your text automatically.

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3ur980po/1/).

Comment: but the height would be the problem then

Comment: So, don't set the height either.

Comment: and this one is simply increasing the width but i dont want like this but width should not overlap with other items and height may be increase to fix it

Comment: So, set the `width` and not the `height`, and set `bottom` to e.g. `10px` instead of setting `top`.